# Client/server network code only working over localhost

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, asyncsocket

I have a simple client/server set up that works fine if the client and server are running on the same machine over localhost.

The code I am using for now can be seen here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx (client)

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx (server)

When I am running the server on a different machine, it is still over an isolated network wherein the only 2 devices connected are the client and the server.

The server will continuously throw the errors

```
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" (most often)
```

and

```
"Only one usage of each socket address is permitted"
```

I have Windows Firewall disabled on the server machine.

One other strange thing the server will sometimes do is repeatedly echo the line 
"Waiting for connection" - You can see this line inside the 'StartListening()' function in the Server code.

Comment: The "strange thing" in your final paragraph isn't that odd - servers are meant to service multiple clients (generally) so as soon as it accepts a connection to one client, it starts trying to accept connections from other clients - and that is indeed what that code implements.

Comment: Yes that would be normal if it proceeded with processing the connection, but it doesn't, it literally echos "Waiting for connection" as many times as a client tries to connect, then proceeds to sit there. After some time has passed it may throw the error that the connection was forcibly closed after a timeout period for each "Waiting" that it echoed.

And I say it is strange because there are no messages between the "Waiting for connection" - it will just have 5 of them in a row sometimes.

Comment: Well.. I added a "Thread.Sleep(200);" just after the 'BeginConnect' call on the client side... now the server appears to process everything normally.

Comment: Now even more silly, if I run the server using IIS Express it works like a charm. If I use regular IIS, it can't figure its life out... Not sure why that would be.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information - and bear in mind that my commenting is just to try to help you improve your question. I'm not sure that trying to host a socket server from within an IIS hosted application makes the most sense - so you may want to expand on your overall goals here, also.